# XPATH: select nodes with certain attribute and child node has no certain attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML which I would like to select the nodes with minOccur="1" but all the child nodes has no such attribute.

My XPATH:

```
//xnode[@type="parent" and @minOccurs="1" and ./child[not(@minOccurs)] and ./child[not(@or)] and ./not(ors) ]
```

XML:

```
<root>
<xnode type="parent" id="1" name="Date" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
    <Othertags id="2" language="FR" name="Date"/>
    <child id="3" name="dateone" maxOccurs="1" value="DONE">
        <def id="4" language="EN" value="this is date one"/>
    </child>
    <child id="5" name="datetwo" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" value="DTWO">
        <def id="6" language="EN" value="this is date two"/>
    </child>
</xnode>
<xnode type="parent" id="7" name="Time" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
    <Othertags id="8" language="FR" name="time"/>
    <child id="9" name="timeone" maxOccurs="1" value="TONE">
        <def id="10" language="EN" value="this is time one"/>
    </child>
    <child id="11" name="timetwo" maxOccurs="1" value="TTWO">
        <def id="12" language="EN" value="this is time two"/>
    </child>
</xnode>
</root>
```

I expect only the second node: id="7" is returned, but it turned out both nodes are returned. What went wrong with the XPath? Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have XML which I would like to select the nodes with `minOccurs="1"` but all the child nodes has no such attribute.

I think you mean:

```
//xnode[@type="parent" and @minOccurs="1" and not(child/@minOccurs)]
```

---

What `not(child/@minOccurs)` means: *"There is no child with a `@minOccurs` attribute."*

What `child[not(@minOccurs)]` means: *"There is a child that has no `@minOccurs` attribute."*

Comment: Yes, brilliant!